# Checkbox marcada/desmarcada ao receber 0/-1 do servidor

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu tenho uma checkbox dentro de uma modal que passa para o servidor ao clicar em um botão o valor 0 se ela não estiver marcada ou o valor -1 se estiver marcada. Agora estou tentando fazer o processo inverso, se estiver gravado 0 quando a pagina carregar a checkbox deve estar desmarcada, se estiver gravado -1 ela deve estar marcada mas não estou conseguindo ter esse retorno, alguem pode me dar uma luz? Estou aprendendo javascript.

Um exemplo do JSON que é enviado para o servidor:

```
{
Cdgrupo: 2,
Grupos: "grupo 2",
Dtalter: "2019-05-28T14:49:03.000Z",
Inativo: -1
},
{
Cdgrupo: 3,
Grupos: "grupo 3",
Dtalter: "2019-05-28T13:58:04.000Z",
Inativo: 0
},
```

Essa é a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="check" id="checkfor" style="position:absolute; left:330px; top:170px;" ></input>
```

E esse é o javascript que eu tentei usar para fazer o retorno:

```
$('#checkfor').ready(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('value', '-1')){
                 $(this).prop('checked', true);
             }
             else
              if ($(this).attr('value', '0')){
                 $(this).prop('checked', false);
             }
});
```

O que eu fiz de errado?

Segue um modelo de como estou fazendo uma requisição em ajax para get:

```
//Get de grupo
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/GetListaGrupos//100/" + pag,       
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao meu ver você está utilizando o evento errado... utilizando o `ready` do Javascript você vai executar a função no momento em que o HTML for montado na tela. O problema é que nesse momento você ainda não possui os dados da sua requisição. O momento de atualizar esse checkbox seria no `success` da função AJAX.

Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/GetListaGrupos//100/" + pag,       
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache:false,
    success: function(data) {
        var element = $('#checkfor');
        element.val(data.Inativo); // Aqui você configura o valor

        // Com o valor já atribuído, você faz as modificações
        if (element.val() == -1) {
            element.prop('checked', true);
        }
        else if (element.val() == 0) {
            element.prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
});
```

Segue abaixo um exemplo. No seu caso, você poderia chamar a função `changeElement` no `success` do AJAX.

```js
// Begin mock
var data = {
    Cdgrupo: 2,
    Grupos: "grupo 2",
    Dtalter: "2019-05-28T14:49:03.000Z",
    Inativo: -1
};

changeElement(data);
// End mock

function changeElement(data) {
  var element = $('#checkfor');
  element.val(data.Inativo); // Aqui você configura o valor

  // Com o valor já atribuído, você faz as modificações
  if (element.val() == -1) {
      element.prop('checked', true);
  }
  else if (element.val() == 0) {
      element.prop('checked', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox"  class="check" id="checkfor" style="position:absolute; left:330px; top:170px;" ></input>
```

Comment: Qual a forma correta de configurar o valor de Inativo em element.val?

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: Feito. Caso não entenda alguma coisa, não hesite em perguntar.

Comment: Não entendi esse begin mock / end mock. Inseri a função changeElement dento da success e o resultado foi o mesmo quando coloquei só a primeira solução, todas as checkboxes aparecem marcadas agora. Em (data.Inativo) eu preciso configurar algum valor? Se sim como eu configuro?

Comment: Não tinha visto que vc tinha atualizado o if e else, fiz a mudança aqui e ainda não funcionou, porém em vez de todas as checkboxes aparecerem marcadas agora estão desmarcadas

Comment: Coloca um `console.log(data);` no `success` do AJAX e coloca o que ele retornou, por favor, isso dá uma noção bem melhor de como os dados estão vindo do servidor.

Comment: {Cdgrupo: "1", Grupos: "Teste123", Inativo: "0"}

0 pois está com a checkbox desmarcada

Comment: Pelo visto ele está retornando como string, então é necessário fazer os `if`s com string também. `element.val() == "-1"` e `element.val() == "0"`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94266/discussion-between-gabriel-midao-and-keven-carneiro).